# NodeJS + Socket.io : simple example working on local (Windows) but not on production (Centos)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying simple example of nodejs and socket.io.

Its work on local (windows)

but not working on production (CentOs 6.8)

what do I need to change on production?

and where should I put app.js ?

(on local I put app.js on my project folder
but on production I put it on root folder *I put it on root because node app.js cant run on project folder)

**Error on browser (looping until I close the browser)**

http://www.domain.com/socket.io/EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1470293560203-1 404 (Not Found)
http://www.domain.com/socket.io/EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1470293560203-2 404 (Not Found)

**app.js**

```
const util  = require('util');
const app   = require('express')();
const http  = require('http').Server(app);
const io    = require('socket.io')(http);
const redis = require("redis");

const host = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';
const port = process.env.PORT || 9090;

http.listen(port, host);
util.log('Listening at http://' + host + ':' + port);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  // util.log("connect");

  var redisClient = redis.createClient();

  redisClient.subscribe('notification');

  redisClient.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    util.log("New message in queue " + message + "channel");

    message = JSON.parse(message);
    // util.log(message.data.data.id);
    socket.emit(channel, message.data);
  });


  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    redisClient.quit();
  });

});
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="notifications"></div>

<script src="//cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost:9090');

  socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);

    var notif = document.getElementById('notifications');

    var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.innerHTML = msg.name + '('+ msg.email +') registered';

    notif.appendChild(div);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen sorry I forgot to add it.. already updated..

Comment: Localhost points to your local nachine, so having it deployed on a server means your web page tries to access the local machine; add a variable to be able to set your `http://localhost:9090` to the correct host.

Comment: so I need to write it for my domain? then http://www.domain.com:9090 right?

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it..
Its just my bad.

first I make sure express,redis,socket.io installed properly.

then at index.html http://localhost:9090 must change into http://domain.com:9090.